# When to use CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String) or CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(String)

Tags: .net, internationalization

When should I call CultureInfo.[CreateSpecificCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx)(String) rather then CultureInfo.[GetCultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo.aspx)(String).  The MSDN documentation is not very clear.

Also is there a way to cheaper check if the name of a culture is valid?

I *think* if you pass “en” rather then  “en-GB” to CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(String) you will get an error, but that CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String) does not mind.  E.g. CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String) can cope if you only pass an language.  *However I am still unclear on this.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you need the culture for. The short names ("en", "fr" etc) are used for neutral cultures, sufficient for language specific resource management. But for numerical and date formatting you need a specific culture, like "en-GB".

And `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");` works fine over here. It is especially intended to get 'a' specific culture for a neutral one.

Answer (score 44):

Cultures are grouped into three sets: the invariant culture, the neutral cultures, and the specific cultures. The culture `en` is a neutral culture while the culture `en-US` is a specific culture.

`GetCultureInfo` will give you whatever culture you requested so if you request a neutral culture you also get a neutral culture like `en`.

`CreateSpecificCulture` will create a specific culture from a neutral culture so if you call `CreateSpecificCulture("en")` the `CultureInfo` returned is for the `en-US` culture. I am not sure how neutral cultures are mapped to specific cultures but there must some table inside the BCL or Windows that contains those mappings and decides that it is the `en-US` and not `en-GB` that is returned. Specifying a specific culture as the argument to `CreateSpecificCulture` will give you that specific `CultureInfo` just as `GetCultureInfo` does.

But there is a somewhat surprising feature of the specific culture created:

> If the culture identifier of the specific culture returned by this method matches the culture identifier of the current Windows culture, this method creates a CultureInfo object that uses the Windows culture overrides. The overrides include user settings for the properties of the DateTimeFormatInfo object returned by the DateTimeFormat property and the NumberFormatInfo object returned by the NumberFormat property.

What this means is that if the specific culture returned by `CreateSpecificCulture` matches the culture selected by the user in **Region and Language** control panel in Windows then any user customizations to that culture is included in the `CultureInfo` returned. E.g. the user may change the long date pattern or the decimal separator used in numbers. Another way to think about this is that when `CreateSpecificCulture` returns a culture that matches the name of `CurrentCulture` it will actually return this culture including any user customizations.

As far as I can tell `GetCultureInfo` does not have this property and will always return a unmodified `CultureInfo`.

And to check if a culture is valid I would use `GetCultureInfo`.

Comment: No slight to Henk, but this is such a better answer! Thanks for pointing out some very interesting differences between the two methods.

Comment: Good answer. Additionally, I believe multiple calls to `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")` will keep returning the same (cached) immutable instance (has `.IsReadOnly` saying `true`). So no extra garbage for the garbage collector. On the other hand, multiple calls to `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")` will, as the name says, create new instances every time, and so are very much like multiple `new` expressions of the form `new CultureInfo("en-US")`.