# Convert.ToDateTime can't converting Day/Month/Year

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core, date-format

Format: Day/Month/Year - C#

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime("28.12.2022 13:45:04")); //Error
```

It throws

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I couldn't find a solution for this. Can you help me?

Comment: `DateTime.TryParseExact` allows you to specify the format(s) of your input.

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0) Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent.

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact("28.12.2022 13:45:04", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the culture corresponding to your date/time format. Example:

```cs
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString, culture);
```

However, it is safer to use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse) than [`Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse):

```cs
If (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, out var date)) {
    Console.WriteLine(date);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date format");
}
```

Note, `Parse` and `TryParse` recognize a wider range of formats than [`ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact) and [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact). The former also work if, for example, the time part is missing or the date contains a month name.

See also: [When to use CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String) or CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(String)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986754/880990)

Comment: One can prefer `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")` over `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, thanks for the hint. I changed that and also linked a question asking for the difference between the two.

Answer (score -1):

You can get short date string like "28/12/2022" a string.
Using;

```
yourDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Localization about your computer setting. It can be change type of your date format. You can use;

```
yourDatetime.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

String to DateTime

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact("datetimeString", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question, which is about going from a `string` to a `DateTime`, not the other way around.

Comment: Oh, you are right.